# Loopback 4 SQL Server connector defaulting to UTC

Tags: sql-server, datetime, loopbackjs

I am trying to save a date to a SQL Server instance that is set to PST. I think I'm running into this issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mssql/issues/24

I've tried various things, including setting TZ="America/Los_Angeles" in the .env file, as well as the useUTC option that's available in the `mssql` module. Set like so:

```
const config = {
  name: 'member_application',
  connector: 'mssql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    useUTC: false,
  }
};
```

Using moment-timezone, I'm able to get the right date value printed out doing this:

```
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

But saving it to the DB, it's always UTC. I've tried a bunch of different ways, including making it a Date object instead of a string, but it's always coming up UTC. Any ideas on how to make this work?